# Get twilio instance in FOSUserBundle event

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I am trying to send SMS to users who register in my website through Twilio, I got the vresh/twilio-bundle and it works fine. 
I am trying to pass twilio instance to the event but I think I am missing something, here is what I am doing:

In config.yml i set the servide like this:

```
services:
    registration.completed.listener:
        class: Jaguar\AloBundle\EventListener\RegistrationEventListener
        arguments:
            entityManager: ["@doctrine.orm.voipswitch_entity_manager", "vresh_twilio"]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber, event: performOnRegistrationCompleted }
```

I have declared the twilio config:

```
vresh_twilio:
    sid: 'xxx'
    authToken: 'xxx'
    version: '2010-04-01'
    retryAttempts: 3
```

Then, in my method I try to get the instance:

```
public function performOnRegistrationCompleted(UserEvent $event) 
{
    $twilio = $event->get('vresh_twilio');
}
```

But it fails...

Any help on this, please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your service setup.

1. You are not actually passing the Twilio instance as you have no `@` sign preceding the service name. `@vresh_twilio` is a service, `vresh_twilio` is just a string.
2. You are passing in an associative array with a key of `entityManager` and a value that is also an array with the values of the service `@doctrine.orm.voipswitch_entity_manager` and the string `vresh_twilio`.
3. You're not passing the Twilio instance in your event you are building a listener with the Twilio instance in the constructor.

Your service should actually look like...

```
services:
    registration.completed.listener:
        class: Jaguar\AloBundle\EventListener\RegistrationEventListener
        arguments:
            entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.voipswitch_entity_manager"
            twilio: "@vresh_twilio"
            // Or
            // - @doctrine.orm.voipswitch_entity_manager
            // - @vresh_twilio
            // Or
            // [@doctrine.orm.voipswitch_entity_manager, @vresh_twilio]
            //
            // As they all mean the same thing and the keys aren't
            // used in your actual service __construct
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber, event: performOnRegistrationCompleted }
```

This would mean your listener would then have a constructor to receive those services like..

```
protected $entityManager;
protected $twilio;

public function __conctruct(ObjectManager $entityManager, TwilioWrapper $twilio)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->twilio = $twilio;
}
```

Meaning that you could then call it in your class using `$this->twilio`.

Also, from looking at the [services that the `Vresh\TwilioBundle`](https://github.com/fridolin-koch/VreshTwilioBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/services.yml) creates it looks like the service that you would want to be injecting would be `@twilio.api` rather than `@vresh_twilio` as it doesn't seem to exist but I may be wrong there (I haven't used the bundle myself).